# django: taking input and showing output in the same page

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

I am quite new to django and struggling to do something very simple. 
I have a `ModelForm` for the  following model:

```
class Queries(models.Model):
    user_id=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    query=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And I am showing the user a simple form that will help in doing the following:

- user will ask a question
- The question will be processed(a database    query will be generated
  based on the question)
- Then the query result    should be shown just beneath the form in the
  same page.

This is how my views.py looks like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from basicapp.models import QueryForm

def index(request):
    form=MyForm()
    real_form=form.getForm(request)
    response=form.response
    return render(request,'basicapp/index.html',{
        'form': real_form,
        'response':response,
    })
class MyForm:
    response=''
    def getForm(self,request):
        form = QueryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            response=form.cleaned_data['query']
            form.save()
        return form
```

For now I am trying simple stuffs,I am taking the value in query field of the form and trying to send it back to the page;so far I am failed. 
This is index.html:

```
<form action=" " method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<p>{{response}}</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If I could do this,I think the query stuffs wont be that tough.The form is working fine,the datas are getting saved in database. Only the `response` string from `views.py` could not be retrieved inside `index.html` after form submission. Can you please help?

EDIT:
Tried following in `index.html` based on Hoff's answer:

```
<form id="myForm" action=" " method="get">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="response">
</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myForm").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('GET'), 
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    $("#response").html(response); // update the DIV
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Still no luck :(

Comment: you should use GET instead of POST. I think you perform a searching

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    questions=None
    if request.GET.get('search'):
        search = request.GET.get('search')
        questions = Queries.objects.filter(query__icontains=search)

        name = request.GET.get('name')
        query = Queries.object.create(query=search, user_id=name)
        query.save()

    return render(request, 'basicapp/index.html',{
        'questions': questions,
    })
```

**html**

```
<form method="GET">
    Question: <input type="text" name="search"><br/>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form><br/><br/>


{% for question in questions %}
<p>{{question}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the whole code :P should all these reside in views.py or the html part should be in index.html? If that where my ModelForm is being used?

Comment: When the user submit the question "if" condition will be trigger and searching for that question start. The output: it will show the list of questions that contains what you have submit.

Comment: I want to save the question that user asked just now,I mean the 'search' thing should be saved.

Comment: I have clarification, did you authenticate the user before they can go in index? or they are anonymous user?

Comment: why you have user_id in your model?

Comment: I have a input field for that,Like there will be a textfield in the form called user_id which can be your name,IP or phone number....just a simple thing.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is an asynchronous post (ajax), which is easy with jQuery, see this answer for a complete solution: [How to POST a django form with AJAX & jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335780/how-to-post-a-django-form-with-ajax-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" name="query" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

you can check if the form was submitted or not (i.e if it's a post request or not):

```
if 'submit' in request.POST: #you could use 'query' instead of 'submit' too
    # do post related task
    # add context variables to render post output
    # add another context variable to indicate if it's a post
    # Example:
    context.update({'post_output': request.POST.get('query','')})
...
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Then in the template, check if context variable `post_output` exists, if it does show the output:

```
{% if post_output %}
    Output: {{ post_output }}
{% endif %}
```

---

In short, the logic is:

1. Check if a relevant `request.POST` dict key exists or not in your view.
2. If the key exists, then it's a post request; add post related context variables and do post related tasks.
3. Check if any post related context variable is available in the template and if it does, show post related output.

**If you don't want to show the output when the page is simply refreshed after a post, pass the `request` object to the template and do a check like this:**

```
{% if request.POST.submit and post_output %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Hoff's answer...

Add URL attribute to ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('GET'),
            url: '/URL-to-ajax-view/',
            success: function(response) { // on success..
                $("#response").html(response); // update the DIV
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Some ajax handler in views.py:

```
# /URL-to-ajax-view/
def ajax_get_response(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.is_ajax:
        form = QueryForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse(form.response)  
    raise Http404
```

Tried something like that?