# Validations in django form

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms, validation

I want validate the django form.Please give me an idea i\how to validate the form ajax in django.
Form is:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" class="form-horizontal" name="jform">{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group formSep">
            <label for="u_fname" class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="aname" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button class="btn btn-gebo" type="submit" name="asubmit">Submit</button>

            </div>
```

Comment: Is this form generated from a Django Form object?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335780/how-to-post-a-django-form-with-ajax-jquery https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax