# Django Invalid Form

Tags: django

I have a modal with a form in it. The issue is that on invalid form it does return the form errors but it also closes the modal dialog box by rendering the home page again. It is also the home page so the return render is needed for the logging in.

**How would I just return to the screen if the post fails.**

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home') 
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()
    context['form']= form
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

modal

```
{% block content %}
 
    <div class="modal fade" id="editProfile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editProfilelCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editProfileLongTtitle">Edit Profile</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {% include 'form.html' %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

form.html

```
{% block content %}

    <form method = "POST" action='.' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div class="container"> 
    {% include 'editProfileModal.html' %} 
    <div class='row'>  
      {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
    </div> 
  </div> 
  {% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in</p>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign up</a>
    
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You mean when `form.is_valid()` returns False ?

Comment: Yes when I enter something incorrectly on the form.

Comment: Can you add `form.html` code

Comment: Sure edited with form

Comment: Is bootstrap modal in home.html template ?

Comment: It is in the home.html template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need shows the modal while you're sending a POST request and the view don't send the redirect. You can try the next poor solution. It's ugly but can work:

```py
def index(request):
    context = {'is_post': False}
    if request.method == "POST":
        context['is_post'] = True
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home') 
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()
    context['form']= form
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

```
{% block content %}
 
    <div class="modal fade" id="editProfile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ... >
        <!-- your content ... -->
    </div>
    <!-- Do this after jQuery loaded -->
    {% if is_post %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load', function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple return `HttpResponse` with form errors.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

if form.is_valid():
   ...
else:
   return HttpResponse(form.errors.as_json())
```

Comment: Sends back the error but the page is now just the error. Should stay at the page with the form errors.

Comment: What error does the page return ?

Comment: Hello @ArundeepChohan in this case you can use ajax with django form these posts will help you [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336591/14457833),[post2](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/work-with-ajax-django),[post3](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

Comment: It just sends form errors depending on what section was incorrect.

Comment: Not sure how to use ajax for this part.

Comment: I don't think you need ajax you can do it with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def index(request):
context = {}
if request.method == "POST":
    print(request.POST)
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home') 
context['form']= form
return render(request, "home.html", context)
```